# Unable to Access Nextcloud Web Interface After Installing in Ubuntu Server 20.04

Tags: ubuntu, server, nextcloud

I just installed nextcloud on my Ubuntu Server 20.04 (local network). The installation finished without problems. Using this tutorial https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-and-configure-nextcloud-on-ubuntu-20-04
so I installed

```
sudo snap install nextcloud
```

setup password

```
sudo nextcloud.manual-install sammy password
```

open ports and created a self signed cert

```
sudo ufw allow 80,443/tcp
sudo nextcloud.enable-https self-signed
```

then I tried login into web interface, and I get "This site can’t be reached" page.
I'm using

```
https://ip_address 
https://ip_address/nextcloud
```

none work... any help appreciated

Comment: Did you follow **Step 3** in the instructions? Are you trying to access the URL from the same, or from a different host (your home computer)? What happens when you try to access `http://localhost` from the same host (the Ubuntu server)?

Comment: if you read the title of the post, I state that I'm installing in Ubuntu Server... means no browser.